# Gauge Dial in OBIEE 11g cannot be displayed

Tags: html, flash, obiee

I'm facing an issue where my Gauge (Dial) cannot be displayed. Instead of the gauge, it displays the image below.

[image: QBB]

Comment: what browser and browser version are you using? 
OBIEE may be defaulted to use Flash to render your graphs.
The exclamation point indicates that the gauge cannot be rendered.

A Flash issue is the most likely culprit.

What version of OBIEE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is an element in the `instanceconfig.xml` file specifying if graphs get displayed [using HTML5 or Flash](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/biee/BIESG/answersconfigset.htm#CIHCGDEJ).

Per [this Rittman Mead blog post](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2015/05/whats-new-in-obiee-11-1-1-9-for-systems-administrators-and-developers/):

"In previous versions of OBIEE graph images were rendered in Flash by default, and PNG on mobile devices. You could force it to use PNG for all images but would loose the interactivity (tooltips etc). Now in OBIEE 11.1.1.9 you can change the default from Flash to HTML5. This removes the need for a Flash plugin and is generally the way that a lot of visualisations are done on the web nowadays. To my eye there’s no difference in appearance:

To use HTML5 graphs by default, edit instanceconfig.xml and under  section add:

**`<DefaultWebImageType>html5</DefaultWebImageType>`**

Note that html5 is case-sensitive. The config file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>  
<WebConfig xmlns="oracle.bi.presentation.services/config/v1.1">  
   <ServerInstance>  
   [...]  
        <Views>  
        [...]  
            <Charts>  
                <DefaultWebImageType>html5</DefaultWebImageType>  
            [...]  
            </Charts>  
        [...]  
        </Views>  
    [...]  
   </ServerInstance>  
</WebConfig>
```

If Presentation Services doesn’t come back up when you restart it after making this change then check the stdout logfile console~coreapplicationobips1~1.log as well as the standard sawlog.log file, both of which you’ll find in `$FMWHOME/instances/instance1/diagnostics/logs/OracleBIPresentationServicesComponent/`. The reason to check the console log file is that Presentation Services will refuse to start if the configuration supplied is invalid, and you’ll see an error message stating this here."